# React Hook to set a state value if null?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a state value like this:

```
const [gamerTag, setGamerTagState] = useState(props.gamerTag);
```

But I need to change it to a empty string if `gamerTag` is null, so I tried this:

```
if (gamerTag === null) {
    gamerTag = "";
}
```

However now I get a syntax warning that `gamerTag` is constant.

How can I set `gamerTag` to an empty string if it's null?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
const [gamerTag, setGamerTagState] = useState(props.gamerTag || '');
```

or you can do:

```
if (gamerTag === null) {
  setGamerTagState('')
}
```

If you want to change a value of a state, you always need to use/call the "set...." function. So in your example you need to call "setGamerTagSetate(Value)"

Comment: Why 2 conditions in the `if` statement?

Comment: Its just checking if "gamerTag" doesn't exist or is null, you could also ignore the first one. It's just to double-check if "gamerTag" isn't "null" but is "undefined", I edited it to suit the requested statement

Comment: _'If you want to change a "useState" you always need to use the "set...." var.'_ I think you meant: _"If you want to change a value/object in your store, you always need to use/call the "set...." function."_  ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix yes exactly, sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: @CarlottaUhlenbusch I actually didn't know that. But aparently, `gamerTag == null` checks for both `undefined` and `null`.

Comment: @JanezKuhar !gamerTag should also check for both values. Because both of these values are "false". [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: @JanezKuhar these are two different answers, you can either do the first or the second, no need to do both.

Comment: @CharlottaUhlenbusch they are not quite the same, are they? `undefined === null` evaluates to `false` (which in turn does not set `gamerTag` to `''` in your second suggestion), whereas `undefined || ''`  evaluates to `''`.

Comment: @JanezKuhar The question asked to only look for "null" not undefined. Yes of course undefined and null aren't the same but still they are both "falsy" values.

Comment: It should be noted that the second approach schedules a re-render (because the state is modified).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may have a little bit of a wrong understanding when it comes to using the react state hook.

You should pass the default value of a state in the function call `useState("default value")`. Then if you want to update the value of the state depending on some condition you should always use `setState(value)`, in your case it is `setGamerTag("")`.

Updating the state value directly is wrong because react depends on using the `setState(value)` function call to update the state, that's why we use `const [state, setState] = useState()` with the const identifier, so that it prevents us from assigning the state directly.
So to fix your error you should do:

```
       if (gamerTag === null){
            setGamerTag("");
        }
```